# `dependencyOverrides` Affecting Compile- and Run-Time?

Tags: sbt

The sbt [Library Management docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version) explain how to override a particular library via `dependencyOverrides`.

The docs' example shows:

> For example, the following dependency definitions conflict because `spark` uses `log4j 1.2.16` and `scalaxb` uses `log4j 1.2.17`:

When adding `dependencyOverrides += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.16"`, does that force the compile- and run-time versions of `log4j` to `1.2.16`?

In the above example, if `spark` uses `1.2.16` and `scalaxb` uses `1.2.17`, what's the compile- and run-time effect of using the above `dependencyOverrides` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no two compile-time and run-time versions of the dependency.

If a transitive dependency is run-time for on dependency (`spark`) but compile-time for another (`scalaxb`) then it becomes compile-time.

Therefore `dependencyOverrides` overrides the automatic version conflict resolution for that dependency by explicitly pinning the version to use.

Comment: I'm not following, Dale. So, will the `spark` dependency, which uses v `1.2.16` (presumably a `JAR`) be re-compiled with version v `1.2.17`?

Comment: No, `spark` which was compiled with v`1.2.16` will just use `log4j` v`1.2.17`

Comment: Ah, and there's **low risk** in that case since the **PATCH** version is only updated? But, if `dependencyOverrides` requires picking a different **MAJOR** version, then that's quite risky? For my second question, let's say that `spark` used v `1.2.16`, but `scalaxb` used v. `2.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions, Dale. Could you please elaborate on what `explicitly pinning the version to use` means? Does that mean that, per my original question referencing the SBT Docs, the dependency listed in `dependencyOverrides` will only include that JAR's classes on the classpath?

Comment: What I mean is instead of letting the conflict resolver decide what version to use, it's overridden, and will only use exactly the version you said. Yes, it'll use that version of the jar, and therefore that JAR's classes on the classpath. Note that it won't add that dependency, it'll only force that version if present in the dependency graph.